# MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033' issue in IBM Integration Bus using IBM WebSphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I've created a message flow in IBM Integration Bus (IIB) where there's a MQInput node, connected to a JavaCompute node, finally connected to a MQOutput node. Both the MQ Input and Output nodes are from the same Local Queue Manager, but are from two separate queues of their own. When I try to send the packet, I get this in my IIB console:

```
[Test Client Info]Checking if Execution group is in use... 
[Test Client Info]Initializing test message monitors... 
[Test Client Info]This monitor is added:MQ: queue:OUTPUT 
[Test Client Info]Creating queue definition file... 
[Test Client Info]Creating queue definition file... 
[Test Client Info]Starting message flows... 
[Test Client Info]Test client is ready to send and monitor messages. 
[Test Client Info]MQ output monitor initialized with: host=localhost|port=0|qmgr=Local_QM1|queue=OUTPUT|serverchannel=SYSTEM.BKR.CONFIG 
[Test Client Info]MQ output monitor started... 
[Test Client Info]MQ input handler initialized with: host=localhost|port=0|qmgr=Local_QM1|queue=INPUT|serverchannel= 
[Test Client Info]MQ input handler sending message... 
[Test Client Error]MQ output monitor encountered an error when attempting to get message: 
[Test Client Error]MQInvocationException: . Wrapped exception: {com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033'.}. 
[Test Client Error]MQ output monitor encountered an error when attempting to get message: 
[Test Client Error]MQInvocationException: . Wrapped exception: {com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033'.}. 
[Test Client Error]MQ output monitor encountered an error when attempting to get message: 
[Test Client Error]MQInvocationException: . Wrapped exception: {com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033'.}. 
[Test Client Error]MQ output monitor encountered an error when attempting to get message: 
[Test Client Info]MQ output monitor is stopping...
```

However in my queues in IBM WebSphere MQ, I get this:

```
 Queue Name      Queue Type    Queue input count    Queue output count
 INPUT           LOCAL          1                   0
 OUTPUT          LOCAL          1                   0
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Is the message put by the output node committed?  You can check by running `DIS QSTATUS(OUTPUT) UNCOM`.  In older version of MQ this will display simple `YES` or `NO`.  In newer version it will display either the number of uncommitted messages or the word `NO`.

Comment: @JoshMc the type(queue) I get is `UNCOM(NO)` , which in this case I'm guessing it's uncommited. But how do I commit the message in IBM Integration Bus, though?

Comment: @halfer got it. (I'm new in asking questions in Slack,sorry my bad.)

Comment: No means they are not uncommitted.

Comment: @JoshMc but the think is that the message was put not from the MQ Explorer, but from IBM Integration Bus instead.

Comment: Your flow didn't generate an output message, check the event log/syslog for errors, or try debugging your flow.

Comment: Btw the input/output count on the queues show how many times those are open for get/put, not how many message there are on the queue.

Comment: By definition, you have an issue in your message flow.What you showed us about the queues status is the number of process listening on it, and it is not normal you have a listening Input process on the input queue.
I suggest you two things : verify that there is an output generated by your java compute node. Check if you correctly used an MQ Output node, because for me it's not possible to have that MQ error on a MQ output node (output means putting message, how could you explain the issue "no message available"). For me you are using a MQGet instead ...